# Removing sensitive data from GitHub, --prune-empty command not executing?

Tags: github

So, I was stupid enough to commit my username and pwd to a GitHub project, now when I'm trying to remove it following these instructions from GitHub, I can't.

When I try to type:

```
git filter-branch --force --index-filter \
'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch php/initialize.php' \
--prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
```

I get the result:

```
fatal: ambigious argument ' --prune-empty': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
```

What does this mean? I've tried to write my file directory differently and it still isn't budging.

Comment: Move prune empty to top line ?

Comment: @user1281385 This does not help. Then -tag-name-filter becomes unrecognized.

Comment: What version of Git are you using? You can check with `git --version`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with a bit of luck. The command I mention above must be spaced and lined as it appears on their 'Removing Sensitive Data' page.

So this:

```
git filter-branch --force --index-filter \
'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch php/initialize.php' \
--prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
```

Is not the same as this:

```
git filter-branch --force --index-filter \ 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch php/initialize.php' \ --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
```